# Is it better to store a value rather than accessing it multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am wondering if directly accessing a variable in a multi-dimensional array is any different than accessing a normal variable.

For example: If I have a 3D int array that tells me the # of players in a lobby on a game server, and I can access it like: `playersConnected[map, gamemode, lobby]`

I am wondering if getting that variable value is any different than getting a value of a regular int.

And in a method I might repeat that statement multiple times to get the value, so if accessing values from multidimensional  arrays are expensive, at what point would it be better to store the value in a normal int? Or would it never really be a situation I should worry about? **eg.** `int connected = playerConnected[map, gamemode, lobby]`.

Comment: So when you actually tested the difference in your actual program what did you find?

Comment: The performance might differ since accessing a multidimensional array can require more "pointer" arithmetic than just accessing a field.  But you should test it yourself to see if it matters, see https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: I'm going to assume the difference is minimal (if noticeable at all...). But seriously, test it yourself first. As for if it's "better", what does that mean? Performance? Readability/maintenance? Memory?

Comment: My bad I guess I should of tested this stuff before asking. I never have done this sort of thing before (profiling code). Testing it in my program rn.. not sure what that means. Do I run a speed test on it or something? Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: I suppose maybe in my circumstance, creating a new script and accessing variable hyperbolically might be easier.

Comment: Actually I'm gonna scrap that, I guess in my circumstance it wouldn't make a significant impact since I'm not calling it thousands of times. Also cause of answer below :)

Comment: @Bureto - You can test a few ways depending on the tools at hand and what you're looking for. Visual Studio has a performance profiler that is nice for checking memory and whatnot (not sure if it's available in all editions - I only have professional). Also, check out the `Stopwatch` class. That is nice for comparing execution times (as long as you're careful where/how you declare things, to keep the test "fair". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Is it the case that your data is actually *rectangular*? That is, if you have five maps, three game modes and seven lobbies, are all 5 x 3 x 7 = 105 combinations valid? If not, then a rectangular array doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Thanks for the tips, I am definitely gonna have to profile my code sooner or later, I'll make sure to check those things out, by the looks of it I also have access to the profiler. Thanks!

Comment: @EricLippert Yup, well kinda. I have a defined set of maps and modes atm (2 each), but the lobbies are not always referenced. My actual array atm is [2,2,500] so 2000 lobbies total. If there is a better way to do this please let me know. :) I heard lists were worse than arrays (can't remember why) so I kinda just rolled with this. Perhaps a `[2,2] <List>` array might work or maybe object pooling would be good for this? Not to familiar with it but maybe those things are something to look into. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not expensive because it does not iterate to find the value, you are just  actually giving the address of a pointer.

for example

`a[20]` simply means the 21st 4 byte (sizeof(int)) starting from the address of `a`.